# Is this the right way to use Java Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have been fiddling around with Java Streams. I have an `Employee` Object, and I'm grouping the object based on age, and I need the employee's name along with that. Is this the right way to do it, or am I using too many loops?

```
employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.age))
    .forEach((age, person) -> {
      System.out.print("In the age " + age + " the following people are present ");
      person.forEach(name -> System.out.print(name.getFirstName() + ", "));
      System.out.println("");
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd separate the data collection from the data presentation.

```
Map<Integer,String> namesByAge = 
    employeeList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getAge, 
                                               Collectors.mapping(Employee::getFirstName,
                                                                  Collectors.joining(","))));
```

Now you can print the names for each age group:

```
namesByAge.forEach((age, names) ->
  System.out.println("In the age " + age + " the following people are present " + names));
```

Hopefully I got the method names correct. Based on your code I assumed `Employee` has a `getAge()` method that returns an `int`, and a `getFirstName()` method that returns a `String`.

Comment: Or `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getAge,Collectors.mapping(Employee::getFirstName,Collectors.toList())))
                .entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
             System.out.println("In the age " + e.getKey() + " the following people are present " + e.getValue());
         });`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed using `.entrySet().stream().forEach(…)` instead of just `.forEach(…)` requires you to deal with the `Map.Entry` methods `getKey()` and `getValue()` instead of referring to key and value just by a name. So it’s much more complicated…

Comment: There is a small difference to the question’s original code as this solution does not have a trailing comma. But for most purposes, it’s an improvement…

Comment: @Eran I really like splitting up the data collection and presentation. It's a much cleaner approach.